# How to control that a method of stateless session bean is executed one at a time?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, ejb-2.x, java-ee-5

Our Weblogic server runs with EJB2.1. Our application gets it requests from messages. If multiple messages come in, concerning the same entity (it does not matter), a method from a stateless method is called multiple times, and they run in parallel. How can I prevent this, so what should I do so they run after each other?

Answer (score 1):

The EJB bean in your EJB container supposes to run in parallel.

The only way I see is to set `max-beans-in-free-pool` to one bean in your `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`, but this will affect your performance drastically. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13719/ejb_jar_ref.htm#EJBPG656

On the other hand, you may migrate to [Singleton EJB](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) that exists from EE6 (EJB3.1), but migrating your EJBs from 2.1 to 3.1 is a long (hard) task.